# Apollo client + Next.js - Adding Authorization token to client request

Tags: authorization, apollo, next.js, react-apollo, server-side-rendering

**GOAL**

I want to populate my `Authorization` header with an access token. I want to store that access token in the Apollo cache as [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens) explicitly state not to store access tokens in local storage (I don't know why the [Apollo Client docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication/#header) seem to think it's okay).

Failing that, I want to store my access token securely and be able to add it to each Apollo Client request to the Apollo Server.

```
const apolloClient = withApollo(({ctx, headers, initialState}) => {
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  // Code here to access local cache.

  return new ApolloClient({

    cache,
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: <apollo server endpoint>,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000/',
        ...headers
      },
      credentials: 'include'
    }),
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
  })
})

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, apollo } = this.props;


    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default apolloClient(MyApp);
```

**TRIED**

- I've tried to access `localStorage` from within the `withApollo` function but it is SSR'd so I'm unable to access that. I was going to use the `localStorage` to set a boolean to check in the `withApollo` function so it'll know the access token has been added to the apollo cache after the redirect.
- I've tried just using the cache with a key storing a boolean to check if the user has signed in which is set in the same function where the access token. If that is true I'd access the access token key and add that to the `Authorization` header. But I was getting issues with setting the initial state overriding the cache set in sign in function.

**OTHER IDEAS**

- I thought I could pass the access token through in the `ctx` argument, but I'm not familiar enough with Next.js to figure out if that's valid way to do it.
- I thought I could pass in a props to the `withApollo` function from a component, but that doesn't seem like it'd be possible.

**QUESTIONS**

- What is the best way to store the access key so as to add it to the Apollo Client with each request?
- I noticed some people are using a `fetch` polyfill, would that be appropriate for this situation? If so, how would that work?
- How does the `withApollo` HOC work and why is it needed to work with Next.js? I've read some of the code behind this, but I don't fundamentally understand why it is needed.

Comment: how do you get the token? ex. after a login?

Comment: The user logs in and they're redirected. The URL they're redirected to contains query strings with the access token. I take the access token from there and use `client.writeData()` to add it to the local cache. I tried using `client.writeQuery()` but I was getting an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my question. I just didn't fully understand the Apollo Client and how to use all of the required packages.

**SOLUTION**

I used `setContext` from the `apollo-link-context` library. It's part of the `link` set of libraries that Apollo Client offers to customise the network request after a graphql operation has started. I set the header in the `setContext` function. Like so:

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // It is also possible to use the local storage method in here.
  const data = cache.readQuery({
    query: ACCESS_TOKEN
  });

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: accessToken ? `Bearer ${data.accessToken}` : ""
    }
  }
});
```

The following is outside the `withApollo` function.

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: '<server uri>',
});
```

The following is inside the `withApollo` function.

```
return new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
  })
```

The docs for how `setContext` are [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#header) and the docs for the `apollo-link-context' are [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/context/).

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how you implemented the apollo client with Next.js, I am also using apollo subscription also, but at first when the subscription didn't find any token it started giving me an error, no token found

Comment: This is the project in which I was using the Apollo client within Next.js, have a look there to see how I did it: https://github.com/codeinaire/nmm-client/blob/main/graphql/createApollo.ts

Comment: This is still happening client-side, you would need a cookie to access the token during SSR as far as I understand

Comment: @codeinaire why does the `authLink` adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header? I thought this header is set by the server in the response, no? What's the use of it in the client side?

Comment: @avepr, you're correct! I was still learning about request, response headers at the time, and the Apollo client so didn't really know what header went were.

Thanks for pointing it out! I'll remove it to avoid confusion.

Comment: How are you getting access to the cache in the apollo link?

Comment: @strap not sure if this is helpful anymore, but I instantiated the cache outside of `authLink` like this: `const cache: any = new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState)`

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a better solution so I'm gonna post it over here. I guess you want to configure your client properly instead of passing the token to each query. I remembered how I used react-query's client. You can do the same here.

My client looks like this:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'

export const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.getItem('personal-access-token')}`
    },
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

If I don't have a token in local storage it'll be set to 'bearer null'. But after I get a new token you should get the Apollo Client's instance and edit Authorization header like this:

```js
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/client'

const setToken = token => {
    client.link.options.headers.Authorization = `bearer ${token}`
    localStorage.setItem('personal-access-token', token)
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

P.S. Make sure to wrap the component which alters the Apollo Client's instance with `ApolloProvider`.

Comment: I'm 95% sure that "bearer" needs to have  a capital "B".

Comment: You're definitely wrong buddy. :) I was implementing GitHub's GraphQL API and it works perfectly, here's the link, check it out or even better, test it.

https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/forming-calls-with-graphql#authenticating-with-graphql

Comment: Sweet! Good to know. Thanks for sharing the docs.